# Append lists for CSV output in Python

Tags: python, append, web-scraping, nested-lists

At the moment I am scraping data from the web and want to output it into CSV.
Everything is working fine but as soon as I append more than one list in the iteration the list has the wrong format.

I start with sth like this:

```
list = [a, b, c]
list_two = [d, e, f]
list_three = [g, h, i]
```

first iteration:

```
list = [list, list_two]
# list = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]
```

second iteration:

```
list = [list, list_three]
```

I get:

```
# list = [[[a, b, c], [d, e, f]], [g, h, i]]
```

I want to have:

```
# list = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

Please help me! I guess it is a easy thing but I do not get it. And I actually struggle to find information on how to append lists.

Comment: Readability counts! IMHO you may have used `list_one` instead of `list` as variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use + to concatenate two lists :

```
list = [ list, list_two ]
list += [ list_three ]
```

You could also use append :

```
list = [ list ]
list.append( list_two )
list.append( list_three )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper list and use append:

For example

```
helperList = []
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_two = ['d', 'e', 'f']
list_three = ['g', 'h', 'i']

helperList.append(list)
helperList.append(list_two)
helperList.append(list3_three)

#helperList >>> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```